# Return included file from function

Tags: php

If i use "return" outside a function in an included php file PHP skips the rest of the file.

Can i do this from inside a function?

test1.php:

```
<?php
echo 'test1';
include('test2.php');
echo 'test2'
?>
```

test2.php

```
<?php
function returner()
{
    return_included_file;
}

returner();

//I don't want this to be executed
echo 'test';
?>
```

desired output:

```
    test1
    test2
```

Comment: Can you tell what will be returned from "return_included_file"

Comment: So what you want to do is prematurely terminate executing the code in the included file without affecting the execution of the main file?

Comment: exactly - "resturn" does just this when called from outside a function. I would love to be able do do it from inside a function

Answer (score 0):

Put an **`exit`** there

```
<?php
function returner()
{
    return_included_file;
}

returner();
exit; // here...

//I don't want this to be executed
echo 'test';
?>
```

### Route 2 :

```
if(!returner())
{
echo 'test';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<?php
function returner()
{
    return_included_file;
}

return returner();

//I don't want this to be executed
echo 'test';
?>
```

By doing so `echo 'test';` will not be executed.

Comment: i want to stop the execution of the included script while continuing with the including script just like an include out of a function does
-
exit will terminate the whole script

Comment: Just use `return` in your included file where your want it to stop execution.

Comment: Then why don't you just do this: `returner(); return;`

Comment: in my example it makes no sense but if the function contains more logic and i produces a result where the execution of the whole included script should be stopped i would love to have a way to archive this without additionals ifs / flags

Comment: I want to terminate the script from inside the function based on results the function produces.
I know i can return something from the function and use "if" after calling it but i would love a way to return "directly"

Comment: To answer your first question: Can I do this from inside a function? I'm afraid that is not possible.

Comment: thats too bad :(. I could use Exceptions but it sure is more code